# Marionette.js dynamically changing template with requireJS not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

Here is the code I have:

```
    render: function () {
        var data = this.serializeData(),
            that = this;
        require(['text!trigger-menu/confirmation/' + that.model.get('type') + '-template.html'],
            function(templateHTML) {
               var html = _.template(templateHTML, data);
               that.$el.html(html);
        });
    }
```

I have 3 different confirmation views that could display. 2 of the 3 are working. The one that isn't looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <% _.each(signupForms, function (signup) { %>
        <li><%- signup.name %></li>
    <% }); %>
    <% _.each(authorizedApps, function (app) { %>
        <li><%- app.name %></li>
    <% }); %>

    <% if ((!signupForms && !authorizedApps) || (!signupForms.length && !authorizedApps.length)) { %>
        <li>All signups</li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

The error is `Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null.`

Anyone else run into this error?

Comment: have checked in debugger your `var html = _.template(templateHTML, data);` line? Which data contained in 'templateHTML, data' and what in result of calling _.template?

Comment: It is possible that you're using an element present in other views, but absent in this one. Just guessing.

Comment: @dennismonsewicz,  This issue is about requirejs behavior. In your code **that.$el.html(html);** will be run in another thread when browser is free and your **templae** is loaded. I expect somewhere else your are looking for an element inside the rendered content but the content was not rendered.

Comment: try putting the call to render the template in the onShow function or onDomRefresh

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the template in the render function, you can do it when you initialize the view:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'marionette',
    'text!templates/template1.html',
    'text!templates/template2.html',
], function ($, _, Backbone, Marionette, template1, template2) {
    var View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            if({YourConditionHere}){
this.template = Marionette.TemplateCache.get(template1);
        }else{
this.template = Marionette.TemplateCache.get(template2);
    });
    // Our module now returns our view
    return View ;
});
```